# Cannot Debug with Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, dyld

I am working on a Java project using JDK 18 on an M1 Macbook Pro. I have been able to run my programs but have been unable to use the debug feature. When I try I get this error:

> dyld[30918]: missing symbol called

Comment: Are you sure JDK 18  ARM version is installed? Similar issues were caused by architecture mismatch, e.g. https://gist.github.com/adrienjoly/e29a6e73fb7e701eefd80ff9bde9abeb

Comment: I have JDK 18 aarch installed and running. Same error

Comment: what about IDE? Do you have apple silicon version https://i.imgur.com/hj4IMgk.png ?

Comment: I do have the m1 specific version downloaded

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this:
1.Start a new shell using Rosetta2

```
$ arch -x86_64 zsh
```

2.In that shell, reinstall the `x64` version of Node.js

```
$ nvm use system
$ nvm cache clear
$ nvm uninstall 16 # or the version you need
$ nvm install 16   # or the version you need
$ nvm use 16       # or the version you need
```

3.Still in that shell, reinstall and build npm dependencies from scratch

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ yarn cache clean
$ yarn install
```

so you may cope with the problem.